# How do I refresh a form after it is shown again?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a program in C# Windows Form Application.

Let me give you a scenario of what I am doing:

1. Log into the program (login system)
2. The program will determine the user's permission value (let's say I'm 3)
3. Depending on the permission value, the main menu will show buttons
   3a. If the user has permission value greater than 2, user will view all buttons
   3b. If the user has permission value less than 2, user will see only 1 button
4. When I logout, I am using .hide to hide the main menu and showing the login form again.
5. I log in another user (with permission value = 1)
6. All the buttons will show, not just only 1 like it should be.

Does anyone know how to "redo" the main menu after logging in, depending on permission value?

Comment: What is the main menu? Is it a control? Is it a form?

Comment: Look at the generated code in your designer file - that might help you. Can you post any of your code for us to look at?

Comment: Maybe you should not just "Hide" the form, but close it. And everytime you open the login form you actually open a new instance of the form instead of re-using the form all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
        const int firstButtonY = 20;
        const int padding = 20;
        int currentY = firstButtonY;

        foreach (var control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control.GetType() != typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Button))
                continue;

            var curButton = (Button) control;

            if (!curButton.Visible)
                continue;

            curButton.Top = currentY;
            currentY += padding + curButton.Height;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of open new instance (in my case, Form3) in Form1 in `Form1_Load`

```
frm3 = new Form3(this);
```

and show after specified event trigger

```
frm3.Show();
```

and cancel the `Form3_Closing`

```
private void Form3_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
     e.Cancel = true;
     this.Hide();
}
```

### We do like this for every event triggered

```
frm3 = new Form3(this);
frm3.Show();
```

and comment the create new instance in `Form1_Load`

```
//frm3 = new Form3(this);
```

and comment the Hide form3 part

```
private void Form3_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //e.Cancel = true;
    //this.Hide();
}
```

because `frm3.Show()` after the form3 `this.Hide()` **WON'T** triggered

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```